# Setting.a variable from an input type, changing it, then load as a URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that you can:

(achieved) 1. enter a url into the input form

2. add a prefix and postfix **of my choice** to the url (prefix = "http://"; postfix = "/postfixtexthere")

3. load the complete url (or value 'urlToLoad') into a web browser

I'm not sure if the variable 'urlToLoad' is correct or not because the 2nd alert doesn't work despite the 1st alert working.

My questions are as follows:
1. Is the variable 'urlToLoad' correct? Does it adapt to what's entered in the input box?
2. How can I then get the variable 'urlToLoad' to load as a website in a web browser?

Hopefully I've done most of the work already. Thanks for the advice.

```js
function checkDomain() {
    
    alert('function executed successfully');
    
    
    var testInput = document.getElementById("checker");
    var testUrl = textInput.value;
    var urlToLoad = "http://" + testUrl + "/postfixtexthere";
    
    alert(urlToLoad);
    

// instructions
 // var urlToLoad = PUT VAR ‘testUrl’ INTO THIS URL, REPLACING ‘__________’: http://__________/postfixtexthere
 
 // THEN LOAD THE URL AS A LINK IN A WEB BROWSER
}
```

```css
.cta-button, a.cta-button {
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #393939;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ff0;

    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>text above the input type</p>
        <div id="misc">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter url" id="checker" value="thisdomain">
        </div>
        <a class="cta-button" onclick="checkDomain()">Check Link</a>
```

Comment: FYI Your variable `testInput` is sometimes `textInput`

Comment: be careful to the name of the variable (testInput  / textInput)

Comment: yes i removed the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this in your local and it should open the URL in new window

```js
function checkDomain() {
    
    alert('function executed successfully');
    
    var testInput = document.getElementById("checker");
    var testUrl = document.getElementById('checker').value;
    var urlToLoad = "https://" + testUrl + "/postfixtexthere";
    
    alert(urlToLoad);
    window.open(urlToLoad);
    

// instructions
 // var urlToLoad = PUT VAR ‘testUrl’ INTO THIS URL, REPLACING ‘__________’: http://__________/postfixtexthere
 
 // THEN LOAD THE URL AS A LINK IN A WEB BROWSER
}
```

```css
.cta-button, a.cta-button {
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #393939;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ff0;

    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>text above the input type</p>
        <div id="misc">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter url" id="checker" value="thisdomain">
        </div>
        <a class="cta-button" onclick="checkDomain()">Check Link</a>
```